# how to get cell value in other sheet based on condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel sheet with data. I want to get data from one sheet to another sheet based on a condition.

```
--------------------------------------------
| Cell A   | Cell B    |                   |
|------------------------------------------|
| TS11     |   yes     |                   |
|------------------------------------------|
| TW22     |   yes     |                   |
|------------------------------------------|
| TS44     |  yes      |                   |
|------------------------------------------|
| Ts11-ab  |   no      |                   |
|------------------------------------------|
| Ts11     |   no      |                   |
--------------------------------------------
```

This is my data in the other sheet. I want these value from above sheet.

Find unique values in column `A`  and provide total in column `B`.

**For example**:  TS11 2 time in column `A` i want it in other sheet like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Cell A   | Cell B  | Cell C (Yes) | Cell D (No)  |   
|--------------------------------------------------|
| TS11     | 2       | 1            | 1            |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| TW22     | 1       | 1            | 0            |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| TS44     | 1       | 1            | 0            |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11-ab  | 1       |              |1             |
----------------------------------------------------
```

In column `C` i want to get values from data sheet based on this condition see above.

**For example**: Count column `B`'s value with column `A` ( How many `yes` and how many `no`).

I hope you understand my question. I have tried many formulas that I found on the internet. But I have not got anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical job for a pivot table:

1. make sure your data has titles
2. go to insert tab - pivot table (this can be slightly different based on you Excel version)
3. move first column's header to "row labels"
4. move second column's header to both "column headers" and "values"

[image]

### Or you can achieve it with functions

Total count:
`=COUNTIF($A:$A,$D2)`

Considering second column too:
`=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$D2,$B:$B,"yes")`

I've included both ranges in one sheet, but of course it'll work with multiple sheets too.

[image]